# Is it multitasking?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Consider the below program

```
myThread = new Thread(
                        new ThreadStart(
                            delegate
                            {
                                Method1();
                                Method2();
                            }
                            )
                            );
```

Is it that 2 threads are getting called parallely(multitasking) or a single thread is calling the methods sequentially?

Comment: Question about basic understanding + “urgent” – is this some kind of exam question?

Comment: @Konrad, should we coin a `urgent` tag? :)

Comment: @Bakkal: Good idea. And any question having that tag is automatically hidden on the start page. ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a single thread.

`Method2()` won't be called before `Method1()` ends.

If you want  `Method1()` and `Method2()` to be each in a separate thread you can do:

```
myThread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Method1));
myThread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Method2));
```

and start them:

```
myThread1.Start();
myThread2.Start();
```

now both can be running concurrently.

**Useful resources:**

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(VS.71).aspx
- http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Comment: Is it possible to make a multithread for the same using the same delegate style.. I mean , if I fire 2 sepearte delegate, will it be multithreaded.

Comment: Could you please write a pseudo code(rough) for the sake of understanding

Comment: NB. in the second case, anonymous methods (introduced by `delegate` keyword) are not needed: `new Thread(new ThreadStart(Method1));`

Comment: So do you mean, for multitasking I need to do thread1 = Thread(new ThreadStart(Method1)); thread2 = Thread(new ThreadStart(Method2)); 

and then thread1.join();thread2.join();

Comment: @Newbie, I tried to edit the answer. To start a thread you call `Start()` on it. What `Join()` does is block (wait) until the thread finishes execution. You should read the links I referenced.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it that 2 threads are getting
>   called parallely(multitasking)

You could check it empirically: declare methoda `Method1` and `Method2` this way:

```
public void Method1 () {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.Console.WriteLine ("Method1: {0}", i);
        Thread.Sleep (2000); // 2 seconds
    }
}

public void Method2 () {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.Console.WriteLine ("Method2: {0}", i);
        Thread.Sleep (2000); // 2 seconds
    }
}
```

And then see whether they are executed sequentially or parallel.

> or a single thread is calling the
>   methods sequentially?

You could check it, say, *analytically*. How many `Thread` objects are you creating? What method are you passing to created threads?

You create only one Thread object, and this thread is to execute this anonymous method:

```
delegate {
    Method1();
    Method2();
}
```

This anonymous method, as can be seen clearly, will execute `Method1`, then `Method2`.

Answer (score 1):

C# 3: Create and start seperate threads. To wait for them to finish, call Thread.Join on all of them.

C# 4: Threading.Tasks.Parallel.Invoke( () => Method1(), () => Method2() );

Comment: Means(c#3.0)  for multitasking I need to do thread1 = Thread(new ThreadStart(Method1)); thread2 = Thread(new ThreadStart(Method2)); and then thread1.join();thread2.join();